# How to make a new configuration for Android in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got the following problem: when I'm trying to execute Android project, I've got the dialog of choosing way for executing my project. I choose "Android project". Some android emulator is executed, all is good. Then I go to preferences and set in "launching" tab the option "Always lauch the previously launched application". I think that all is done, but when I'm trying to execute my project again I've got the dialog "Create, manage and run configurations". There are no Android items in left menu excluding "Android JUnit Test". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The previously run project must be open in Eclipse, open the project before selecting "Run Last Launched" from the Run menu.